# Environmental variables in Wix, where are the binary files

Tags: wix, windows-installer, jpackage

I have version WiX 4.0.3, I can't find the binary files to add them to the PATH for WiX 4.0.3. Where can I find them?

Can someone help me?

The console returns:

```
` Running candle.exe
[11:39:19.574] jdk.jpackage.internal.PackagerException: Error: Invalid or unsupported type: [msi]
        at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Arguments.generateBundle(Arguments.java:694)
        at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.internal.Arguments.processArguments(Arguments.java:565)
        at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.main.Main.execute(Main.java:92)
        at jdk.jpackage/jdk.jpackage.main.Main.main(Main.java:53)
[11:39:19.571] Can not find WiX tools (light.exe, candle.exe)
[11:39:19.571] Download WiX 3.0 or later from https://wixtoolset.org and add it to the PATH.
`
```

Answer (score 0):

WiX v4 has a [very different command-line](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/intro/#nettool) than WiX v3. `candle.exe` and `light.exe` don't exist any longer, and you don't install WiX v4 the same. It's all different. You'll need to teach `jpackage` how to work with WiX v4.